# how do I find the inverse of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the inverse of this problem? Thanks.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} -4e^{4t} \sin(5t) &-4e^{5t} \cos(5t)\\
2e^{4t} \cos(5t) &-2e^{5t} \sin(5t) \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Could you please write it in Latex it's not very clear the way you wrote it.

Comment: Is this what you meant...$$A=\begin{pmatrix} -4e^{4t} \sin(5t) &-4e^{5t} \cos(5t)\\
2e^{4t} \cos(5t) &-2e^{5t} \sin(5t) \end{pmatrix}$$?

Comment: yes sorry dont know how to write it that way.

Comment: Why did you undo the edit?

Comment: @user125984 Hi: I edited it to make it look like Zhoe's suggestion. You reverted it to the unreadable version, but I'm hoping that was an accident.

Comment: Sorry didnt know what i was doing.

Comment: Please check the [$\tt LaTeX$-MathJax help page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In this way, your next question will look quite fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You can use the inverse matrix rule for a $2x2$ matrix

$${\begin{pmatrix}a& b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}}^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d& -b \\ -c&a \end{pmatrix}$$

Can you take it from there? The $ad-bc$ term should simplify rather nicely.

Comment: For the det(a) i got 1/8e^9^t is that right?

Comment: Probably yes. You wrote ${8e^{9^t}}$ and probably meant ${8e^{9t}}$. Do learn to use Mathjax notation!

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you divide $A$ for $8e^{9t}$ you have an ortonormal matrix, the inverse of an ortonormal matrix is only its transpose so do $B=(1/(8e^{9t})A$ then $B^{-1}=B^t$ and you have an easy solution